# Flex media queries: left-right to top-down

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to make it 2 column on 767px and 1 column 480px? Is it possible to make flex same height when it turns to 1 column?

This is what I have so far:

```css
.col-container {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
}
.col-container>.col {
 padding:10px;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
}
.col:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color:green;
}
.col:nth-child(even) {
 background-color:blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .col-container { 
  flex-wrap: wrap;    
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
 <div class="col">
  <h2>Column 1</h2>
  <p>Hello World</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="col">
  <h2>Column 2</h2>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="col">
  <h2>Column 3</h2>
  <p>Some other text..</p>
  <p>Some other text..</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

This flex show four column

[image: four column]

to full width to 767px

[image: one column]

Comment: 1.add width :50% for colum in 767px

Comment: 2. just make sure to change flex direction and justify-content adding media query of 480px with column width 100%

Comment: 1. I already try to add width:50% for column media queries but it just stay 1 column to left and to right side empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your css code to the below code it works.

As i guess i think you are using `width:50%` on container, like i meantioned in comment it should be for the child element i.e, `.col` in your code. I hope this solves what you are looking for. :)

I have added your code on codepen in case you need it => https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKgWgm

```
    .col-container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .col-container>.col {
      display:block;
      padding:10px;
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
      border:1px solid red;
    }
    .col:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color:green;
    }
    .col:nth-child(even) {
      background-color:blue;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .col-container { 
        flex-wrap: wrap;    
      }
      .col-container .col{
        width:50%;
        min-height:250px;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
      .col-container .col{
        width:100%;
        min-height:200px;
      }
    }
```